# C language - print the 3 most frequent characters from user input string

Tags: c, loops, ascii, c-strings

The goal of this program is to ask user for input and print the **3 most frequent** characters from user's string. After few days I managed to make this kind of work. I mean kind of because if input will be "aaaaaaabbbbbccxz" program will work just fine, but if input will be "abc" program prints wrong values. Same with "aabbc", empty string, etc. I've been trying to fix that but with no luck. I have no idea what to do.
There's my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 100
/*
ask user to type letter string and load it to the array.
Count apperance of ASCII characters in the string
Print 3 most frequent characters from the string and how often they appeared.
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int ascii[256] = {0};
    char str[N];
    int z, i, j, k, top, top2, top3, index, index2, index3;
    printf("Type your string: \n");
    scanf("%s", &str);
    for(i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
{
   ++ascii[str[i]];
}

top = ascii[0];
index = 0;
for(z = 0; str[z] != 0; z++)
{
     if( ascii[str[z]] > top)
     {
         top = ascii[str[z]];
         index = z;
     }
}

printf("The most frequent is %c - was %d times.\n", str[index], top);

top2 = ascii[0];
index2 = 0;
for(j = 0; str[j] != 0; j++)
{
     if( ascii[str[j]] > top2 && ascii[str[j]] < top)
     {
         top2 = ascii[str[j]];
         index2 = j;
     }
}

printf("second most frequent %c %d times.\n", str[index2], top2);

top3 = ascii[0];
index3 = 0;
for(k = 0; str[k] != 0; k++)
{
     if( ascii[str[k]] > top3 && ascii[str[k]] < top2 && ascii[str[k]] < top)
     {
         top3 = ascii[str[k]];
         index3 = k;
     }
}

printf("3rd most frequent %c %d times.\n", str[index3], top3);

    
    return 0;
}
```

### EDIT:

it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int ascii[256] = {0};
    char str[N];
    int x, y, z, i, j, k, top, top2, top3, index, index2, index3, len;
    
    do
    {
    printf("String input here: \n");
    fgets(str, N, stdin);
    //scanf("%s", &str);
    }
    while (str[0] == '\n');
    for(i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
{
   ++ascii[str[i]];
}

    top = ascii[0];
    len = strlen(str);
    index = -1;
    for(z = 0; str[z] != 0; z++)
    {
        if( ascii[str[z]] > top)
        {
            top = ascii[str[z]];
            index = z;
        }  
    }
    if (index == -1) return printf("This string is empty\n");
    else if (top == 1 && len > 1) return printf("There is no repeated character in that string\n");  
    else if (top == len) return printf("This string contains a single character '%c' - repeated %d times\n", str[index], top);
    else {
        // Checks the special case where several characters are repeated n times
        char characters[len+1];
        int count = 0;
        for(i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
        {
            if (ascii[str[i]] == top && str[i] != characters[count-1])   
                characters[count++] = str[i];
        }
        characters[count] = 0;

        if (count > 1) return printf("The most frequent characters are '%s' - repeated %d times.\n", characters, top);
        else printf("The most frequent character is '%c' - repeated %d times.\n", str[index], top);
    }


top2 = ascii[0];
index2 = -1;
    for(j = 0; str[j] != 0; j++)
    {
            if( ascii[str[j]] > top2 && ascii[str[j]] < top)
            {
                top2 = ascii[str[j]];
                index2 = j;
            }
    }
    if (index2 == -1) 
    {
    }
    else if (top2 == 1 && len > 1)
    {
    }
    else if (top2 == len)
    {
    }
    else {
        char characters[len+1];
        int count = 0;
        for(y = 0; str[y] != 0; y++)
        {
            if (ascii[str[y]] == top2 && ascii[str[y]] < top && str[y] != characters[count-1])   
                characters[count++] = str[y];
        }
        characters[count] = 0;

        if (count > 1 )
        {
        }
        else printf("The 2nd most frequent character is '%c' - repeated %d times.\n", str[index2], top2);
    }


top3 = ascii[0];
index3 = -1;
for(k = 0; str[k] != 0; k++)
{
     if( ascii[str[k]] > top3 && ascii[str[k]] < top2 && ascii[str[k]] < top)
     {
         top3 = ascii[str[k]];
         index3 = k;
     }
}
    if (index3 == -1) 
        {
        }
        else if (top3 == 1 && len > 1)
        {
        }
        else if (top3 == len)
        {
        }
        else {
            char characters[len+1];
            int count = 0;
            for(x = 0; str[x] != 0; x++)
            {
                if (ascii[str[x]] == top3 && ascii[str[x]] < top && ascii[str[x]] < top2 && str[y] != characters[count-1])   
                    characters[count++] = str[x];
            }
            characters[count] = 0;
    
            if (count > 1 )
            {
            }
            else printf("The 3rd most frequent character is '%c' - repeated %d times.\n", str[index3], top3);
        }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For input `abcd`, I think there will not be any 3 most frequent characters, because all characters are occurring same number of time. You missed that case.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula Right, rn I have no idea how to fix that. I'll be looking for solution online or if you have any idea that you don't mind sharing that'd help me a lot

Comment: See this link :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-find-second-frequent-character/    It has similar problem. It will help.

Comment: @brushcil You just have to declare another variable `third` and write another `else if` . (From the link)

Comment: I thought I got it, but at this point I really don't know https://pastebin.com/NF0GZGB7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this and handle the second and third cases using a similar logic :

```
    len = strlen(str);
    index = -1;
    for(z = 0; str[z] != 0; z++)
    {
        if( ascii[str[z]] > top)
        {
            top = ascii[str[z]];
            index = z;
        }  
    }
    if (index == -1) return printf("This string is empty\n");
    else if (top == 1 && len > 1) return printf("There is no repeated character in that string\n");  
    else if (top == len) return printf("This string contains a single character '%c' - repeated %d times\n", str[index], top);
    else {
        // Checks the special case where several characters are repeated n times
        char characters[len+1];
        memset(character, 0, len+1);
        int count = 0;
        for(i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)
        {
            if (ascii[str[i]] == top && !strchr(characters, str[i])) 
                characters[count++] = str[i];
        }
        characters[count] = 0;

        if (count > 1) return printf("The most frequent characters are '%s' - repeated %d times.\n", characters, top);
        else printf("The most frequent character is '%c' - repeated %d times.\n", str[index], top);
    }
```

Comment: I tried to follow this method, but couldn't compile it because "ld returned 1 exit status" [https://pastebin.com/kA9Bch1B]. I've started programming class this october and don't know much how to apply ideas to programs

Comment: The codes above are only a fragment that you must paste within your main function to replace the form starting at `index=0;` and going through the first `printf`statement (included). I tested it and it should work. I would like to help you to fix that but, unfortunately, the link you provided in your comment doesn't contain any code.

Comment: Should I make vars len and memset both int and = 0 and for every next frequent char make e.g. len2, memset2, characters2, etc?

Comment: `len` is the length of the string (sorry I forgot to show that it in my codes) so, no, it remains the same through the 3 cases. `memset` is not a var but a function that initializes the array with zero values. But in fact it was not strictly necessary since I set the null termination again later : so I removed it. Anyway all that form starting with `else {`and going to the end is in another scope (within braces) not visible for other statements so you don't have to worry about the var names even if you reuse them for the next cases.

Comment: I have only 1 problem left at this point: if my input will be "qwqwqwqwdcdcdcxzz" program it will print "The most frequent characters are 'qwqwqwqw' - repeated 4 times." I don't know how to make it say 'qw 4 times'.

Comment: I had a test to check if the character was already collected but it tested only the last collected one which is wrong in that case because the two characters alternate. I replaced that with a more general test, but I had also to reinsert the `memset` call to ensure that the `characters` array terminates with a zero since it is used as a string in the test.  The test is `!strchr(characters, str[I])` which checks if `str[i]` is already present in `characters`. I have no time to test it myself now, but it should work. Let me know if it's ok.